# How do I listen to DataStore changes in ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

So I am making an application, where if the user selects a different location, the query of the api should instantly change as well and should return new data?

How can I implement flow observer inside the viewmodel?

```
    val cityName: String = settingsManager.cityName.first()
    val countryName: String = settingsManager.countryName.first()
    val response: Response<AladhanApiResponse> = repo.getAdhanTime(cityName, countryName)
```

Comment: Share more code, where do you use datastore? what's the type of `cityName`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [combine operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#combine) to create a flow of your response based on changes of your other fields. However, your other fields (cityName, countryName) must be flows too. You can either use a [MutableStateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/) or some other logic to create them in your settingsManager.

Here is how you would then create a flow of your responses that will automatically change when location is changed:

```
val cityNameFlow = flowOf("London", "Barcelona").onEach { delay(100) } // Replace with flow of your cityName from settings
val countryName = flowOf("UK", "Spain").onEach { delay(150) } // Replace with flow of your countryName from settings

val responseFlow = combine(cityNameFlow, countryNameFlow) { cityName, countryName ->
    getAdhanTime(cityName, countryName)
}

responseFlow.collect { response ->
     // Called whenever new response is available (cityNameFlow or countryNameFlow changes) 
     println(response) 
}
```